# Is `ts_headline` intended to highlight non-matching parts of the query (which it does)?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm running some complex FTS queries in Postgres 13.4 and discovered some behavior in `ts_headline` that's unexpected, at least to me, and wasn't sure if I've come across a feature or a bug.  ;)

Initial sanity check:

```
SELECT plainto_tsquery('english', 'red dog') @@ to_tsvector('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');

-- false
```

No surprises: the `tsquery` evaluates to `'red' & 'dog'`, the document does not contain `'red'`, no match.  But when I try to get headlines:

```
SELECT ts_headline('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', plainto_tsquery('english', 'red dog'));

-- The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy <b>dog</b>.
```

The same happens with the FOLLOWED_BY operator (`<->`); you can replace `plainto_tsquery` with `phraseto_tsquery` (or construct your own `tsquery` literals).  It still highlights fragments that aren't actually matches.

The problem is not (or at the very least, not entirely) a result of trying to call `ts_headline` without having a real match.  My original situation was actually more like:

```
SELECT ts_headline('I want a red dog, but not a black dog.  No red cats, either.', phraseto_tsquery('english', 'red dog'));

-- I want a <b>red</b> <b>dog</b>, but not a black <b>dog</b>.  No <b>red</b> cats, either.
```

In that case, given that the `tsquery` evaluates to `'red' <-> 'dog'` (i.e., "red" immediately followed by "dog"), I'm surprised by the last two highlights.

The [documentation for `ts_headline`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) says:

> Displays, in an abbreviated form, the match(es) for the *query* in the *document*,

which leads me to believe this is a bug, but [the longer blurb on highlighting results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE) only says the function

> returns an excerpt from the document in which terms from the query are highlighted

and indeed, terms from the query *are* highlighted...

I've tried messing with the options argument to `ts_headline`, and nothing has changed this behavior.

So...  Am I calling it wrong, is *it* wrong, or do I just have wrong expectations for its behavior?

(Seems tangential to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102954/postgresql-ts-headline-not-matching-ts-query-correctly), but it seems to be describing a *different* bug.  And I can't tell what exactly is or isn't happening or supposed to happen in [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431200/ts-headline-postgresql-behavior), so who knows if it's related or not.)

Comment: Not an answer, but there's an [open ticket from 2018](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/152461454026.19805.6310947081647212894%40wrigleys.postgresql.org) that describes this, duplicated from [this Database Administrators SE question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204856/ts-headline-not-highlighting-properly-for-operator).  It appears to just be a low priority bug that no one's tried to fix yet.

Comment: have you tried setting the dictionary for ts_headline, i.e. `ts_headline('english', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')` ?